# AWS cognito: In mobile app how to set token expiry to infinite

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, authorization, amazon-cognito

Im using cognito developer authentication provider as my access control for my mobile app. Problem is in mobile apps, once the user logs in he/she doesnt have to login again. But with AWS cognito the token only lasts some 1 hour or so. How can I make sure the token expiry is set to infinite maybe 1 year or so. Please advice

thanks,
Rajan

Answer (score 2):

When you use the InitiateAuth (login) function, you get 3 tokens: 
Identity, access and refresh.

By default the identity and access tokens expire after 1 hour.
The refresh token can last up to 3650 days.

When the identity and access tokens expire, you can still use the refresh token to get new ones.

So, to answer your question, if you set the refresh token's expiry time to the maximum, your user needs to re-login once every 10 years

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to ask for user to login again even if the token is expired. You can cache the existing login details (could be a token or the credentials depending on how your developer authentication has been setup) and pass it your backed everytime you need to refresh the token.

Comment: Thankyou so much. So the login details are email and password. You are saying I keep them in the cache and call the login function again when the token is expired? Also in a few example I see people manually setting credentials.expired=true; why do they do it

Comment: Typically long lived token (refresh token) vended by the login systems are cached. If your login system provides it, you should use it to cache the user session. 
'credentials.expired' is set to true manually if you want to force a call to Cognito for new credentials with the new logins set in the credentials provider.

Answer (score 1):

On user login, aws cognito gives

- Identity token
- Access token
- Refresh token.

When the access token expires, use refresh token to get a new set of tokens.